# Singapore Passport Holder & UK Permanent Resident

Tags: uk, passport-renewals, uk-residents, singaporean-citizens

I am a Singapore citizen and a UK Permanent Resident. My passport is expiring on 06 April 2018.

I am travelling to Singapore between December 21st and 31st. Am I allowed to re-enter the UK with my passport expiring in April or will the Immigration stop me?

I am concerned I will not get the renewal in time for my travel.

Comment: I am not sure but can't you enter the UK with your residence card?

Comment: @Newton, you need a valid passport as well to enter the UK.  Typically one presents both the passport and residence card to the border agent.  The online guidance does say you can "present your passport *or* residence card", so perhaps you can only show one to the agent, but I don't think that overrides the requirement for all non-EEA citizens to have a valid passport.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements for entering the UK [are found here](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control).

Unlike some countries, the UK does not have a requirement of six months' passport validity when you enter.  Instead, the guidelines [simply state](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk) (for non-EEA nationals):

> It must be valid for the whole of your stay.

Obviously that doesn't apply to you, since as a permanent resident you can stay as long as you want.  I don't think there is any issue here, and you shouldn't have a problem.

(The issue here is ability to leave the country if and when required to do so.  For someone who was only allowed to stay in country a limited time, an expired passport would be an impediment to meeting the legal obligation to leave--hence the validity requirements, and associated requirements like having a valid ticket home.  But this is not a concern for a permanent resident).

Comment: this^ just show your passport and biometric residence permit